# Change default connection dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, connection

I have a middleware in Laravel application that change database connection dynamically:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    Config::set('database.default', 'mysql_'.$request->segment(1));
    DB::reconnect('mysql_'.$request->segment(1));
    app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
    if (Auth::check() && session('locale') != $request->segment(1))
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('login');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

This work, the default connection change but the model connection stey the old.

In dump of a model I have:

"mysql_es" is default connection changed by url segment (/es)

"mysql_it" is a old default connection before change by middleware.

can anyone tell me why?

Thanks

Comment: I think that is because the route model binding use the default dB before the middleware

Comment: Maybe `DB::purge('mysql');`?

Comment: I tried but not work. I solved changed db connection in RouteServiceProvider

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is purging the connection.

```
// Purge the current database connection, thus making Laravel get the default values all over again...
DB::purge('default');

// Now set the new connection
config(['database.default' => 'mysql_it']);

// ! Reconnect and close previous connection
DB::reconnect('default');

// Ping the database.
// This will throw an exception in case the database does not exists or the connection fails
Schema::connection('default')->getConnection()->reconnect();
```